# Hibernate-Entity Not found exception -Spring batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have @manytoone relationship from person table to country table on country-id (foreign key)

In country table -id 's started from 1.

However while saving data in person table .

I'm getting an error

EntityNotFound:unable to find country id 0

Also ,there is an error

HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org. hibernate. engine. loading. internal. CollectionLoadContext@5da03062<rs-
HikariPro onLoadContext -

HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries

What will be the possible causes of this.

This error occurred in spring batch application

1.checked table data --there is no entry in country table with id 0

Comment: You prolly have a relationship to `Country` on the `Person` class and in that relationship you have the ID 0

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not set `countryId = 1`, on the new person object which you are trying to persist